# Integration testing grails spring security plugin?

Tags: security, spring, plugins, grails, spring-security

I have this:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_HELPDESK', 'ROLE_ADMIN'])
class MyController {
    def edit = {
    }

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
    def uploadForUser = {
        params.userId = params.id
        forward(controller: 'someController', action: 'someAction', params: params)
    }
}
```

and an integration test I think should fail:

```
public void test_uploadForUser_unauthenticated(){
    myController.params.id = "testUser"
    myController.uploadForUser()
}
```

And yet the tests pass. Is there any way to test controllers annotated with the spring security plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These annotations are analyzed by `SpringSecurityFilter`, so they don't work if you don't have an actual HTTP request performed.

Thus, you need either to switch to checking the roles by conditionals inside the actions, like being done [here](http://nerderg.com/Grails), or test it with WebDriver/Geb or some simpler framework -- very nice approach is presented in [Grails Security Plugin itself](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/4d917ed848d16b457d89a62dca7e8cce2289a84b/webtest/tests/AnnotationSecurityTest.groovy).

Comment: Very concise explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Artur Nowak, your second link is broken. Any idea where the code moved to?

Comment: @SirCelsius I've updated the link to point to a previous revision.